# how to select buttons / elements in protractor in a page designed in material design?

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am developing a application in angularjs with material design, when I am testing in protractor, I couldn't find anyway to select the buttons to assign a click event ?  I found one reference : http://www.gofaqs.com/961/what-are-the-selectors-in-protractor?show=961#q961, but couldn't get much information related to material.

any pointers in this direction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is *nothing specifically made for material design in Protractor* and you have to use the [available locators](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy). You can ask application developers to add meaningful ids, classes or custom data attributes to key elements which you operate in during testing which would help to build more reliable locators.

Note that you can also create your own custom locators via [`addLocator`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.addLocator).